# Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts

Tags: xargs, echo

I want to reclaim some of the disk space as it only has 7.5GB of space when I check on disk space information I usually see this message consuming much of the disk,

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts
```

My command to clear disk space is this

```
cat machines.txt | xargs -I {} ssh {} bash -c "'sudo echo " " > /var/log/messages'"
```

I have a text which has the ip of my machines. I'm trying to figure out why `sudo echo " "` command is not working for me. its giving me this prompt.

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/agilos/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why you are trying to echo your IP into /var/log/messages... what is the output of cat machines.txt |xargs -l {} ssh ?? I think your syntax is wrong and you should start checking that first.

Comment: AdrianG, I've ,moved your command from the title into the question, and copied the error into the title. If it's not the command you're using please [edit] your question to correct it. In particular, it's unlikely that `machines.txt` is executable; are you missing `cat` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah so the syntax is cat machines.txt | xargs -I {} ssh ubuntu@{} bash -c "'sudo echo " " > /var/log/messages'" and I'm kinda new to linux so I'm not sure if there are other ways to clear the log for /var/log/messages. The reason why i want to clear the file is to reclaim some of the disk space as it only has 7.5GB of space when I check on disk space information I usually see this message consuming much of the disk.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix typos and to add extra data. Make it easy for people to help you by keeping everything in one (readable) place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command looks like you might be trying to destroy the current contents of `/var/log/messages` on a number of hosts at once. **This looks like something a malicious hacker might do in an attempt to cover their tracks.**

I'm assuming the `machines.txt` at the beginning should be `cat machines.txt` instead. If not, then it means `machines.txt` would actually be an executable, and that you're naming your files in a way that is designed to be obscure; this is another thing that is sometimes done by malicious hackers trying to keep their tools hidden in a hacked system.

Because you are piping data to `xargs`, the piped data takes the place of the standard input stream for the `xargs` process. By default, the child processes of `xargs` will get their standard input redirected from `/dev/null` so as not to interfere with the piped input to `xargs`. The `ssh` command will detect that its standard input is not a terminal, and will assume it is running in batch mode, i.e. it will attempt to do its job without interacting with the user at all.

The `xargs -I {} ...` is executing the remaining part of the command line once for every line in `machines.txt`. The error messages might be output by the `ssh` command executed for the very first line of `machines.txt`, or a number of lines may be already silently executed successfully before the one of the instances of the `ssh` command encounters an error; from the output, it is not possible to say with complete certainty which of the `machines.txt` lines was being used when the error happened.

The first message:

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/agilos/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

is a warning; SSH is trying to record the public host key of each new system it connects to into the `known_hosts` file so that it can be checked on future connections, but this time it failed to do so for some reason. The actual connection attempt may still proceed.

The second message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

indicates that your SSH authentication key was not accepted by one of the hosts. Since the `ssh` command is running in batch mode, it knew to not even try password authentication, as the batch mode usually means the command is being run in a context that does not allow interaction with the local user. So one of the SSH connection attempts failed because it was not able to authenticate.

The third message:

```
xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

comes from the `xargs` command, as it detects one of the `ssh` commands it is executing based on the contents of the piped-in data has exited with an error. SSH exits with status 255 any time a connection error occurs; any other error code will be the result of the remote command executed.

You're trying to execute the command `sudo echo " " > /var/log/messages` on a number of hosts using `xargs`, but the command itself will not do what you're trying to do: the shell will set up redirections first before executing the command, and so with this command line the `sudo` command will end up executing just the `echo " "` part with root privileges, while the redirection (the `> /var/log/messages` part) will run as the user you logged in as... and so most likely will fail to do anything at all.

If your instances had an appropriately-setup `logrotate` and permission to run `sudo` without password prompts, then you might be able to run an extra round of log rotation on all instances with something like:

```
xargs -I {} ssh {} sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf < machines.txt
```

This way no tricky quoting-within-quoting is needed, either.

If you really need to truncate the actual `/var/log/messages`, the "redirect to a file with root permissions through sudo" problem is typically solved by using the `tee` command with `sudo` instead. So your command line might look like this:

```
xargs -I {} ssh {} bash -c "'echo " " | sudo tee /var/log/messages'" < machines.txt
```

But you'll need to fix your SSH authentication issue first, and for that, you'll need to know which host is failing the SSH key authentication. Also, `echo " "` adds an unnecessary space character in the beginning of the first log line; it's better to just truncate using `/dev/null` instead.

```
xargs -I {} ssh {} bash -c "'sudo tee /var/log/messages </dev/null && hostname'" < machines.txt
```

This will output the hostname of each system that has truncated its log successfully, so you'll know which instance in your `machines.txt` is failing the SSH authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. You are correct on messages part but I'm just trying to emptying this log file for that moment so as to reclaim some disk space for my instances. Is there another way of executing echo " " > /var/log/messages using xargs?

Comment: Thank you so much solved my problem on truncating the /var/log/messages issue part by using this command 'xargs -I {} ssh {} bash -c "'sudo tee /var/log/messages </dev/null && hostname'" < machines.txt'. I'm still finding out my problem on the 'Failed to add the host to the list of known host' its able to run the command but its just displaying that error/notification on my terminal.

Comment: Check the ownership & permissions of the `/home/agilos/.ssh/known_hosts` file (should be owned by the `agilos` user; it may have changed to owned by `root` if you have run `sudo ssh ...` at some earlier time), and ensure that the filesystem containing that file is not 100% full.